# Textbooks of scheme theory with detailed proof, no classical algebraic geometry and so on

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes

I would like to learn scheme theory. But it seems that there are many books of scheme theory, so I look for the textbooks that satisfied my below conditions:

1. not so particular about classical algebraic geometry.
2. proofs is detailed
3. category theory, abelian category and homology algebra are premised
4. prepare for abelian varieties and arithmetic geometry

If you know the textbooks satisfied such conditions, I hope you'll tell me.
I'd appreciate if you could answer the question.

Comment: What about EGA?

Comment: I can't read French, but if I don't understand something in Qing liu's book, I would like to read EGA.

Comment: You don't need to know any French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by classical algebraic geometry but Lius book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" is a very good reference.
I still think Hartshorne chapter 2 is a must for everyone doing algebraic geometry.
There are a few books coming from lectures: Rave Vakils tremendously detailed lecture notes "The Rising Sea" for example. More formally, Scholzes notes "Algebraic Geometry" when he gave the class.
These are not official notes, but can be found online.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. For exanple, Varieties' definition have modern definition as to be defined an integral, separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field and classical definition. I am interested modern algebraic geometry. I will read the book you presented. Thank you.

Comment: All of them look like good references (I didn’t know about Scholze’s notes). QL might be a bit light for category theory or homological algebra.

Comment: yes I don't know if category theory is a good thing to start with, I comes along the way if you want to do comohology and derived categories or even fancier things? But that's just my opinion haha that was exactly the reason why I liked QL because its down to earth algerbaic!